# Unable to unzip a downloaded file

Tags: swift, alamofire

I created a route on my nodejs server that sends a zip file of images. But unfortunately every time I make a request to the server I am able to download the zip file to but I can seem to be able to unzip file. I get the error message "unarchivable" and localized description of the error message is "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Zipper.Zipper.ArchiveError error 0.)" The nodejs route works perfectly fine with postman and my Android app.

Alamofire: 5.0.0-beta.5
swift: 4.2

I found this 
[Unzipping Error The operation couldn’t be completed. (Zip.ZipError error 1.) between ViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633644/unzipping-error-the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-zip-ziperror-error-1-bet)

but I couldn't make sense it. I did try using a completion handler for the download process but still got the same error message

// swift code

```
do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("zipServe"), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

    let destination: DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("zipServe").appendingPathComponent("pig.zip")

        return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }

    AF.download(self.main_url + "imagesAll/shop/", method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers, to: destination)
        .downloadProgress { progress in
            print("Download Progress: \(progress.isFinished)")
        }
        .response { response in
            if response.error == nil, let imagePath = response.fileURL {
                do {
                    print(imagePath)
                    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: imagePath.path) {
                        print("File exists")
                        try FileManager().unzip(item: imagePath.absoluteURL, to: self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("zipServe"))
                    } else {
                        print("File not found")
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
    }


} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

I should be able to see a list of the images contained within the zip file.